# Laravel raw query questions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have problem with my 2 queries:

Query #1:

```
$rows = DB::table(self::TABLE_NAME)
        ->selectRaw('subforum_id, count(1) as count')
        ->groupBy('subforum_id')
        ->get();
```

Is there a possibility to write this by eloquent?

And the second:

```
 Topic::where('id', $topicId)->update(['posts_count' => +1]);
```

I need to add +1 to column posts_count - how to do this?

And can someone explain me what for is RAW?

Comment: Why is the 1st one causing problems?

Answer (score 1):

You can write `RAW` query like:

```
DB::table(DB::raw("Update topic set posts_count = posts_count + 1"))
```

`RAW` query is available in almost every framework, it is used for making complex query where framework methods are not enough to make your query.

Comment: Is possibility to do this by eloquent + raw?

Comment: Yes, you can. Like: `DB::table('users')
                 ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
                 ->where('status', '<>', 1)
                 ->groupBy('status')
                 ->get();`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this

With Eloquent:
`Topic::find($topicId)->increment('posts_count');`

Or this with query builder:

```
DB::table('topics')->where(['id'=>$topicId])->increment('posts_count');
```

According to laravel query builder documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#increment-and-decrement